# Call jQuery valid() without updating the screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to know if a form is valid or not. But calling `valid()` actially updates my screen which puts the error messages out there. I need to know if my form is valid without interacting with the UI at all. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "without interacting with the UI?" What do you want to trigger the validation?

Comment: I want to say `if ($(form).valid()) { do whatever }`. When I do this, the valid() call updates my screen (i.e. "The FOO field is required").

Comment: The problem is that .valid() only works on clicking a button as per the docs on the plugin site.

Comment: I am clicking a button. Is there no way to make valid() not update the UI? If so I will remove the plugin and close the question.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I thought you meant validating without you interacting with the UI. Let me post an answer.

Comment: Sounds good. I call validate() then valid() and want to do something based on the results. But I don't want to tell the user something is not valid yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - replacing the variables with your stuff.

if you are just validating without submitting - do this:

```
    var yourform = $('#yourform');
    yourform.validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    return true;
  }
});

    $('a.validateit').click(function(){
    var isvalid = yourform.valid();
    if (isvalid){
    // do stuff
    } else {
        alert('form is not valid');
    }
        });
```

If you're doing it on submit:

```
    var yourform = $('#yourform');

    yourform.validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    return true;
  }
});

    yourform.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var isvalid = yourform.valid();
    if(isvalid){

     $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: yourform.attr('action'),
                            data: yourform.serialize(),
                            success: function(response) {
                                     //do stuff
                            },
                            error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                     // do error stuff
                            }
                    });
          });
    } else {
    alert('form is not valid');
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I had not thought of using preventDefault and then serializing and sending myself manually. That's pretty nifty.